# ftp a file and save it on local machine ( tar the file)

Tags: shell, scripting, ftp

I need help with a shell script. I want to ftp file from a server and save it on my local computer using a shell script. Can someone point me into the right direction, or show me sample code? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is something I attempted.

logic: Ask the user for file name, 
           log into the server,save the name, execute a find command on the server...if file found, save the path and ftp the file into my local machine but tar it. if the file is not found..display some kind of error message and go to top of the loop.

Any help would be greatly appreaciated

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#Author: Joseph
#Purpose: To find a file and ftp it 

#declare variables
FILE=""

#start while loop
while [ "$FILE" != "quit" ] ; do

    #Asks for file to be found
    echo "Enter the filename to find:"
    read FILE 
    PATH=$(ssh xxxxxx@xxx.xxx.xxx 'find / -name $FILE 2>notPath.txt')

    #day=$(date)
    #name="$FILE.tgz"
    #PATH=$(find / -name $FILE 2>notPath.txt)

    #tar czf $day/$name $PATH
    #echo "$day/$name"
    echo $PATH
    echo ""
    exit
done
```

Comment: pretty good. What problems are you experiencing? Do you know about shell debug/verbose mode with `set -vx`? That will show you how your cmds are being evaluated and executed. But doing a `find / -name` can take hours on a big machine. I understand the desire to have the computer help your user, but unless you're sure that the `find` can complete in less than ~1 min(?) you're user won't be happy with that. Best to require a full path to file, or path as 1 arg and file as 2nd arg OR use $PWD on remote as place to look. `day=$(date)` will be really ugly, use `day=$(date +%Y%m%d)`. Good luck.

Comment: I don't see where you "get" the file from the remote. That can be done with `scp` or `sftp`, but requires managing passwords, which is a whole hellish issue in its own right. Search here for `[bash] sftp` or [bash] scp` for a many different takes to your problem. If you're doing this to learn shell programming then continue with this track, else consider reading a little bit about rsync, but that requires more of a sys-admin mind set, and still requires work. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with rsync, which you can use for tons of useful things (aka synchronizing files locally, remotely, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have configured ssh without password to the remote server from you local machine.

your code only work when ssh without password is set else not.

to set ssh without password use:

> ssh-keygen -t rsa
>
> ssh b@B mkdir -p .ssh
>
> cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh b@B 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'

where 'b' is remote server username and 'B' is remote server IP or Hostname (if /etc/hosts set).

or, you will require expect query to pass user name and password to login into the server before sending find command.